# Are memory chargers (boosters) permissible?

Tags: halal-haram, food

I want to know if [Complan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complan) with memory chargers (boosters) is halal (allowed)?

If yes, please provide supporting stances.

Comment: You'll have to provide more details if you want an answer.

Comment: If it contains the things which is haram then only it will be haram otherwise taking nourishing food is halal.

Comment: We seek effortful questions showing prior research.  Asking about permissibility without indicating a reason it's not the [default ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36838) is considered [off-topic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663).  Please [edit] the question accordingly.